# Does the convergence of a special series imply the other?

Tags: calculus

Let $\{x_{k}; k\geq 1\}$ be such that $x_{k}\rightarrow \infty$. 
Suppose $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x_{k}e^{-x_{k}}<\infty$. Is the following true?
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x_{k}^{2}e^{-x_{k}}<\infty.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that this is not true.
Choose, for example,
$$
x_k = \log(k \log^3 k).
$$
Then you have
$$
x_k e^{-x_k} \sim \frac{1}{k \log^2 k},\qquad
x_k^2 e^{-x_k} \sim \frac{1}{k \log k},
$$
hence the first series is convergent whereas the second one is divergent.